# Java - Indexing an Interface?

Tags: java, interface, indexing

This is probably a really stupid question, so please forgive me. But this morning, I've come across a piece of Java syntax that I am completely unfamiliar with. The syntax is as follows:

```
public MyInterface[] getThings() {
    return new MyInterface[0];
}
```

Obviously, I've changed the name of the interface, and of the method, but otherwise this code sample is unchanged.

I'm confused by this syntax, as it seems to be indexing an interface/class (not even an object)?! Also, the use of the `new` keyword, to instantiate an interface?!

I've genuinely attempted to Google this, in order to find an answer. But as it's syntax that I'm unfamiliar with, in addition to using the line of code itself as a search term, I've just been guessing at what terminology to use. And unfortunately, I've failed to find anything that explains this syntax for me. Hence, I'm hoping that someone on Stack Overflow might be kind enough to help me to understand this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just creating an empty array. No instances of the interface are being created. It's equivalent to:

```
return new MyInterface[] { };
```

Or:

```
MyInterface[] array = {};
return array;
```

Specifically, it's an *ArrayCreationExpression*, as seen in [section 15.10 of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.10).

Comment: Thank you. I don't know how I didn't realise that =/ . I got caught up in the idea of indexing.

Answer (score 1):

The function returns an empty array supposed to holding objects of type MyInterface.

It's similar as if you would use String[] to return an array of strings.

Comment: Oh yeah, of course. It's not indexing at all, it's declaring an array. Now I feel really stupid =/ . Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

it just returns an empty array of MyInterface (size is 0). an array is an array, no matter, of which type the array is. it can be a primitive datatype, a class or an interface, too.